# C++: both classes do not run concurrently

Tags: c++, multithreading, mbed

its my first time here. My code is suppose to make two ultrasonic sensors function at the same time using an mbed. However, i cant seem to make both classes void us_right() and void us_left() in the code run concurrently. Help please :(

```
#include "mbed.h"
DigitalOut triggerRight(p9); 
DigitalIn echoRight(p10);
DigitalOut triggerLeft(p13); 
DigitalIn echoLeft(p14);
//DigitalOut myled(LED1); //monitor trigger
//DigitalOut myled2(LED2); //monitor echo
PwmOut steering(p21);
PwmOut velocity(p22);
int distanceRight = 0, distanceLeft = 0;
int correctionRight = 0, correctionLeft = 0;
Timer sonarRight, sonarLeft;

float vo=0;

// Velocity expects -1 (reverse) to +1 (forward)
void Velocity(float v) {
    v=v+1;
    if (v>=0 && v<=2) {
        if (vo>=1 && v<1) {                 //
            velocity.pulsewidth(0.0014);    // this is required to
            wait(0.1);                      //
            velocity.pulsewidth(0.0015);    // move into reverse
            wait(0.1);                      //
        }                                   //
        velocity.pulsewidth(v/2000+0.001);
        vo=v;
    }
}

// Steering expects -1 (left) to +1 (right)
void Steering(float s) {
    s=s+1;
    if (s>=0 && s<=2) {
        steering.pulsewidth(s/2000+0.001);
    }
}

void us_right() {
    sonarRight.reset();
    sonarRight.start();
    while (echoRight==2) {};
    sonarRight.stop();
    correctionRight = sonarLeft.read_us();
    triggerRight = 1;
    sonarRight.reset();
    wait_us(10.0);
    triggerRight = 0;
    while (echoRight==0) {};
  //  myled2=echoRight;
    sonarRight.start();
    while (echoRight==1) {};
    sonarRight.stop();
    distanceRight = ((sonarRight.read_us()-correctionRight)/58.0);
    printf("Distance from Right is: %d cm \n\r",distanceRight);
}

void us_left() {
    sonarLeft.reset();
    sonarLeft.start();
    while (echoLeft==2) {};
    sonarLeft.stop();
    correctionLeft = sonarLeft.read_us();
    triggerLeft = 1;
    sonarLeft.reset();
    wait_us(10.0);
    triggerLeft = 0;
    while (echoLeft==0) {};
  //  myled2=echoLeft;
    sonarLeft.start();
    while (echoLeft==1) {};
    sonarLeft.stop();
    distanceLeft = (sonarLeft.read_us()-correctionLeft)/58.0;
    printf("Distance from Left is: %d cm \n\r",distanceLeft);
}

int main() {
    while(true) {
        us_right();
        us_left();
    }
   if (distanceLeft < 10 || distanceRight < 10) {
            if (distanceLeft < distanceRight) {
                for(int i=0; i>-100; i--) {       // Go left
                    Steering(i/100.0);
                    wait(0.1);
                }
            }
            if (distanceLeft > distanceRight) {
                for(int i=0; i>100; i++) {       // Go Right
                    Steering(i/100.0);
                    wait(0.1);
                }
            }              
    }
        wait(0.2);
}
```

Comment: Classes don't run. Functions run.

Comment: Why did you expect them to run concurrently? I don't see any threading related code in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some mechanism to create new threads or processes. Your implementation is sequential, there is nothing you do that tells the code to run concurrently.

You should take a look at some threads libraries (pthreads for example, or if you have access to c++11, there are thread functionality there) or how to create new processes as well as some kind of message passing interface between these processes.

Answer (score 0):

Create two threads, one for each ultrasonic sensor:

```
void read_left_sensor() {
    while (1) {
        // do the reading
        wait(0.5f);
    }
}

int main() {
    Thread left_thread;
    left_thread.start(&read_left_sensor);

    Thread right_thread;
    right_thread.start(&read_right_sensor);

    while (1) {
        // put your control code for the vehicle here
        wait(0.1f);
    }
}
```

You can use global variables to write to when reading the sensor, and read them in your main loop. The memory is shared.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you have placed code outside of your infinite while(true) loop. This later code will never run. But maybe you know this.

```
int main() {

    while(true) {
        us_right();
        us_left();
    } // <- Loops back to the start of while()

   // You Never pass this point!!!

   if (distanceLeft < 10 || distanceRight < 10) {
            // Do stuff etc.
   }
   wait(0.2);
}
```

But, I think you are expecting us_right() and us_left() to happen at exactly the same time. You cannot do that in a sequential environment.

Jan Jongboom is correct in suggesting you could use Threads. This allows the 'OS' to designate time for each piece of code to run. But it is still not truly parallel. Each function (classes are a different thing) will get a chance to run. One will run, and when it is finished (or during a wait) another function will get its chance to run.

As you are using an mbed, I'd suggest that your project is an *MBED OS 5 project*
(you select this when you start a new project). Otherwise you'll need to use an RTOS library. There is a blinky example using threads that should sum it up well. [Here is more info](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/latest/APIs/tasks/rtos/#thread).

Threading can be dangerous for someone without experience. So stick to a simple implementation to start with. Make sure you understand what/why/how you are doing it.

**Aside:** From a hardware perspective, running ultrasonic sensors in parallel is actually not ideal. They both broadcast the same frequency, and can hear each other. Triggering them at the same time, they interfere with each other.

Imagine two people shouting words in a closed room. If they take turns, it will be obvious what they are saying. If they both shout at the same time, it will be very hard!

So actually, not being able to run in parallel is probably a good thing.